# Ordering a MySQL Table Based on a Positive or Negative Integer in a Column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a **MySQL** table called `example` with columns `my_order` and `alt_order`.

**Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:**

- If `alt_order` is null, order by `my_order`.
- If `alt_order` is not null, order by `my_order`, but position the row above or below where it should be based on the integer in `alt_order`.

**Pseudocode:**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  example
ORDER BY
  IF(alt_order IS NULL, my_order, [MOVE UP OR DOWN BASED ON alt_order])
```

**Ideal Output:**

```
+--------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| desc   | my_order | alt_order | notes                               |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| Item 1 | 1        | NULL      | Ordered by my_order                 |
| Item 3 | 122      | -1        | Ordered by my_order + alt_order     | <-- Move up one row
| Item 2 | 50       | NULL      | Ordered by my_order                 |
| Item 4 | 127      | NULL      | Ordered by my_order                 |
| Item 5 | 205      | NULL      | Ordered by my_order                 |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

**Attempt:**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  example
ORDER BY
  IF(alt_order IS NULL, my_order, my_order + alt_order)

# The problem with using this method is that the value of my_order
# has to be the same as the value of above it to work.
```

---

> **Edit:**
>
> If the `alt_order` is positive ***n***, then it should move down ***n*** rows. On the other hand, if the `alt_order` is negative ***n***, then it should move up ***n*** rows.

Comment: What would you do, if *Item 2* would have *alt_order = +1*?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel If the `alt_order` is positive **n**, then it should move down **n** rows. On the other hand, if the `alt_order` is negative **n**, then it should move up **n** rows.

Comment: I guess you missed my point. *Item2:alt_order=+1* => you move it down to *rowNr 3* and *Item3* gets *rowNr 2*. Now *Item3* has *alt_order=-1*. Do you move up to *rowNr 1*? There are many other cases that would make your requirements incomplete. Another example: *Item2:alt_order=+1* and *Item3:alt_order=+1* - do you swap them twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the result you specify could be achieved by ordering the rows twice. First, order by `my_order`, and assign an initial "row number". Then, take a second pass through, ordering by the initial "row number" adjusted by the "row offset".  Because "row number" and "row offset" are both integers, when we add them (rn=2  + ro=0) we can get a collision (rn=3 ro=-1). To make the ordering more determinate, we can need to adjust

```
 SELECT s.desc
      , s.my_order
      , s.alt_order
      , s.notes
   FROM ( SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
               , t.desc
               , t.my_order
               , t.alt_order
               , t.notes
            FROM `example` t
           CROSS
            JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0 ) i   
           ORDER BY t.my_order
        ) s
  ORDER
     BY s.rn + IFNULL(s.alt_order,0.5)
```

Comment: I like it very much. So I'm trying to understand how this works, and I am unsure why you used **0.5** at the end on the last `ORDER BY`. Do you mind explaining that particular part?

Comment: I added the 0.5 to make the ordering more determinate.  If we get a row with rn=3, and the alt_order is -1, to move that row "up one" in the order, if  we add rn and alt_order, 3-1=2. That gives MySQL two rows that need to be at the same position... it's a coin toss what order they're going to be in. I added the 0.5 to break the tie, so that row we wanted to "move up" one will in fact "move up".

Answer (score 0):

The query below may work for you or send you in the right direction.  By using a CASE statement in your ORDER BY you can control the way your data sorts.

```
SELECT * FROM `example`
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN `alt_order` IS NULL THEN `my_order` ELSE (`my_order` + `alt_order`) END)
```